# Is there a way using JavaScript to simulate a certain key keypress when pressing another key?

Tags: javascript, keyboard, event-handling, dom-events, keydown

Like pressing "a" key and typing "b". There seem to be lots of old questions similarly to this one, but the answers don't seem to be working. Don't know if it's due to `KeyboardEvent.initKeyEvent()` being deprecated or my code having flaws, but I can't get it right.

Here's an example of some things that I've tried:

```
document.addEventListener("keydown", evt => {
  evt.target.dispatchEvent(new KeyboardEvent('keydown', {"keyCode": 9, "which": 9}))
})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

New Answer:

```js
const data = [
  "apple",
  "banana",
  "pear",
  "orange",
  "lemon",
  "lime",
  "grape",
  "cherry",
  "peach",
  "plum",
  "grapefruit",
  "watermelon",
  "kiwi"
]

let suggestions = [];
const container = document.getElementById("data");
let index = 0;

function handleChange(e) {
  const value = e.target.value;
  container.innerHTML = "";
  index = 0 ;
  suggestions = value ? data.filter(ele => ele.toLowerCase().includes(value)) : [];
 
  suggestions.forEach(ele => {
    const suggestion = document.createElement("div");
    suggestion.textContent = ele;
    container.append(suggestion);
  })
}



function handleKeydown(e) {
  if (e.keyCode === 9 && suggestions.length) {
    e.preventDefault();
    e.target.value = suggestions[index];
    index === suggestions.length - 1 ? index = 0 : index += 1;
  } else if (e.keyCode === 13) {
    container.innerHTML = ""
    index = 0;
    suggestions = [];
  }

}
```

```html
<div> Type A Fruit </div>
<input type="text" onkeydown="handleKeydown(event)" oninput="handleChange(event)" />
<div id="data"> </div>
```

Old Answer:

There doesn't seem to exist a way to open select dropdown artificially; this was the best implementation I could come up with.

```js
let selected = false;

function handleSelect(e) {
  if (e.keyCode === 9 && !selected) {
    e.preventDefault()
    const options = Array.from(e.target.children);
    if (!e.target.classList.contains('open')) {
      e.target.setAttribute('size', e.target.options.length)
      e.target.classList.toggle('open')
    } else {
      const index = options.findIndex(option => !!option.selected)
      if (options[index + 1]) {
        options[index + 1].selected = true;
      } else {
        options[0].selected = true;
      }
    }
  }
  if (e.keyCode === 13) {
    e.preventDefault();

    if (e.target.classList.contains('open')) {
      e.target.classList.toggle('open')
      e.target.setAttribute('size', "initial")
      selected = true;
    }

  }

 if (e.keyCode === 38 || e.keyCode === 40) {
   if (!e.target.classList.contains('open')) e.preventDefault();
 }
}

function handleBlur() {
  selected = false;
}

function handleClick(e) {
  Array.from(e.target.children)[1].focus();
}
```

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
}

label {
  width: 100px;
  pointer-events: none;
}

select {
  pointer-events: none;
}

.open {
  position: absolute;
  left: 110px;
}
```

```html
<div> click and hit tab </div>

<div class="container" onclick="handleClick(event)">
  <label for="cars">Choose a car:</label>

  <select onkeydown="handleSelect(event)" onclick="handleClick(event)" onblur="handleBlur()" name="cars" id="cars">
    <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
    <option value="saab">Saab</option>
    <option value="mercedes">Mercedes</option>
    <option value="audi">Audi</option>
  </select>
</div>
```

Comment: okay, but if I want to set a "tab" key action on another key?

Comment: I've got a ```text input``` with a ```datalist```. User starts typing => a dropdown with fitting ```options``` from the ```datalist``` appears. Now, to navigate through the options while I've got focus inside an input I can't use ```tab``` and ```shift```+```tab```: it will change the focus from the input to the next or previous html flow element, I have to use ```arrow down``` and ```arrow up``` keys, which is not suitable enough. So, under certain conditions, I want to change ```tab```'s default action to the ```arrow down``` action.

Comment: I basically want input/options behavior to be similar to the one you have in browser's address search bar: you can type, you can choose from the dropdown via tab and if, say, there's only one fitting option left from the dropdown, you just press enter to autocomplete.

Comment: Got it; that should be doable in 2 different way, just trying to see if the easier way works. I'll update when i find out.

Comment: thank you for the dedication to the matter. If there are any information sources that can get me there, I'll be happy to look into them :)

Comment: @Alex_Flowers there doesn't seem to be a way to artificially open a select dropdown, though I updated my answer with a close attempt.

Comment: Yeah, as I've said, I'm working on a text input with the datalist attached, not a select tag, so I wonder if this solution works for that case too?

Comment: thank you, I'll see if I can implement it with keeping it workable :)

Comment: @Alex_Flowers I updated my answer with a new snippet that I think better reflects what you are trying to do; I kept the old one as well.

Comment: It does work! Unless you:
1) type smth to open datalist options dropdown
2) use tab to navigate through the options
3) type smth else or use backspace to partially or fully delete what you"ve typed
4) use tab again.
In that case it returns undefined

Comment: Fixed; just needed to reset index on input.

Comment: thank you, the site doesn't let me upvote your answer due to its questionable politics which is not letting me upvote till my account reaches a certain level of a "reputation", otherwise the answer definetely would have received a vote :)